# Using Formula for model specification generates error while creating models in R

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models, mumin

I fitted a mixed model of the following form:

```
global.mod <- lmer(log(y) ~ 
                       x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + x5 + (1 + x1|a/b),
                       REML = FALSE, data = lmerDat,
                       na.action = 'na.fail', control = lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e4)))
```

I then use `predge` to create combinations of model below which works fine.

```
require(parallel) || require(snow)
clusterType <- if(length(find.package("snow", quiet = TRUE))) "SOCK" else "PSOCK"
clust <- try(makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 4), type = clusterType))
clusterEvalQ(clust, library(lme4))
clusterExport(clust, "lmerDat")

 model.set <- pdredge(global.mod, clust, 
                      m.lim = c(2, NA), rank = AIC, extra = "adjR^2", trace = 2)
```

I then tried to specify my models in a slightly different format as below:

```
 PredictorVariables <- names(lmerDat)[c(5:9)] # this is x1 till x5
 fixed.part <- paste("log(y) ~", paste(PredictorVariables, collapse=" + "))
 random.part <- paste('(1 + x1|a/b)')
 Formula <- formula(paste(fixed.part, random.part, sep = " + "))

 global.mod <- lmer(Formula, data = lmerDat, na.action = 'na.fail', control = 
 lmerControl(optimizer="bobyqa",optCtrl=list(maxfun=2e4)), REML = FALSE)    

 require(parallel) || require(snow)

 clusterType <- if(length(find.package("snow", quiet = TRUE))) "SOCK" else "PSOCK"
 clust <- try(makeCluster(getOption("cl.cores", 4), type = clusterType))
 clusterEvalQ(clust, library(lme4))
 clusterExport(clust, "lmerDat")

 model.set <- pdredge(global.mod, clust, 
                      m.lim = c(2, NA), rank = AIC, extra = "adjR^2", trace = 2)
```

However, this gives me the follow error

```
 Error in sprintf(gettext(fmt, domain = domain), ...) : 
 invalid format '%d'; use format %f, %e, %g or %a for numeric objects
```

Unfortunately the latter is how I want to do the model specification since apriori I do not know what will be the names of the predictors in `names(lmerDat)[c(5:9)]`. Could anyone help me understand the error and how to resolve it?

**EDIT**

my traceback output is as follows (please note that this is on my original data instead of the dummy data above).

```
 7: sprintf(gettext(fmt, domain = domain), ...)     
 6: gettextf(Message, ..., domain = domain)    
 5: structure(list(message = as.character(message), call = call), 
   class = class)      
 4: simpleError(gettextf(Message, ..., domain = domain), Call)
 3: stop(simpleError(gettextf(Message, ..., domain = domain), Call))
 2: cry(, "number of non-fixed predictors [%d] exceeds the allowed maximum of %d (with %d variants)", 
   nov, novMax, nVariants)
 1: pdredge(global.mod, clust)
```

Comment: I am not familiar with `snow()`, can you create your vector of formulas as a character vector and run it using `lapply()` like this `lapply(formula_vec, function(x) lmer(formula(x), data = lmerDat, etc...)` (I know this works outside of snow). Heads up though, it will stop if you run into converge or misspecification issues with any of the models

Comment: Please add a reproducible code or at least a `traceback()` output following the error.

Comment: Okay. I have added `traceback()` output after I get the error

Comment: It is just a glitch with error message formatting. Anyway, the error `dredge` tries to print is due to the excessively large number of terms in your model. The upper limit is 32 (there is no simple way to work it around).

Comment: Okay thank you very much for the answer.